# Entity Framework Database First, Interface for a self referenced entity hierarchy

Tags: entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

I have a self referenced entity Category, that has subcategories. It works very well.

Now I want to implement a JsTree helper, but because I have another different project that uses a similar structure (Category is  a 100% similar entity in both projects) I want to implement the helper in a class library and make it available for both.

This is the code generated by the Entity Framework, no changes here:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="MyModel", Name="Category")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Category : EntityObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("MyModel", "FK_Categories_Categories", "Categories1")]
    public EntityCollection<Category> Subcategories
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<Category>("WebDirectoryModel.FK_Categories_Categories", "Categories1");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<Category>("MyModel.FK_Categories_Categories", "Categories1", value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Interface I wrote:

```
    public interface ICategory
{
    System.Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }
    System.String DefaultName { get; set; }
    EntityCollection<ICategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

And then I added another partial class for Category implementing ICategory:

```
    public partial class Category : ICategory
{
}
```

The problem is that I get the following compiling error:

> Error   6   'MyProject.EntityFramework.Models.Category' does not implement interface member 'ICategory.Subcategories'. 'MyProject.EntityFramework.Models.Category.Subcategories' cannot implement 'ICategory.Subcategories' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection < ICategory > '.

Any idea to solve this problem? What am I doing wrong? Category is implementing ICategory so Subcategories (the ICategory collection) in ICategory should match, isn´t it?

I´m using EF 4.4 but I think the problem is not related with that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I´ve solved it, I haven´t run the application yet but it compiles and makes sense. This is what I´ve done:

ICategory more generic and also only the getter, I don´t need the setter:

```
public interface ICategory
{
    System.Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }
    System.String DefaultName { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<ICategory> Subcategories { get; }
}
```

Then the partial class Category:

```
public partial class Category : ICategory
{
    IEnumerable<ICategory> ICategory.Subcategories
    {
        get { return Subcategories.Cast<ICategory>(); }
    }
}
```

I´ll update the answer after I test this to confirm that it works. I´m writing the helper.

---

I edit to confirm that this works.